# PrimaryKeyRelatedField does not include value in validated_data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a serializer that is suppose to create an object on a `POST` request. However when run `serializer.validated_data` it does not include `currency` in the `QueryDict`. if i for instance change from `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` to `IntegerField` it includes it, but that is not optimal when it is suppose to point to a record in another table. Why is it that currency is not being included in `validated_data` when i use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`?

**serializer**

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    deposit_amount = serializers.FloatField()
    receive_amount = serializers.FloatField()
    currency = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('task', 'deposit_amount', 'receive_amount', 'currency')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at', 'currency')


    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Invoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

When i call `request.data` in my viewset it returns:

```
{'currency': 2, 'task': 1, 'deposit_amount': 2.01, 'receive_amount': 118652.7}
```

however when i return `serializer.validated_data`:

```
OrderedDict([('task', 1), ('deposit_amount', 2.01), ('receive_amount', 118652.7)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 currency = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
```

This field is flagged as `read_only`. You will not find it in the `validated_data` as they are write operations.
You have to turn the `read_only` flag to False to achieve that.